# Django model autorelation sublevel

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to development under the Django framework and I have not found a documentation or tutorial that specifies how to translate to models the data design that I will specify.

As an oversimplified example we will devise a production / assembly chain in which a product can depend on / consume X products for its construction.

It would be represented by the following structure:

[image: Data structure diagram]

Which would translate to the following SQL (on SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE [Product] (
  [Id] Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  [Name] varchar(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [ProductRequirement] (
  [Id] Int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  [Product] Int,
  [ProductRequired] Int,
  [Quantity] Int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ([Product]) REFERENCES Product([Id]),
  FOREIGN KEY ([ProductRequired]) REFERENCES Product([Id]),
)
```

But I can't figure out what its representation would be in a Django model, I've tried the following interpretation:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    
class Requirement(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    productRequired = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    Quantity = models.DecimalField(blank=False, max_digits=2, decimal_places=0)
```

But it exhibits the error (when executing 'makemigrations'):

```
Production.Requirement.product: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Requirement.product' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Requirement.productRequired'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Requirement.product' or 'Requirement.productRequired'.
Production.Requirement.productRequired: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Requirement.productRequired' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Requirement.product'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Requirement.productRequired' or 'Requirement.product'.
```

The question is: which model could satisfy this structural requirement?

Comment: In your schema quantity would be the required quantity. For example if you buy a product that requires 2 AAA batteries, it will be the a link to the product AAA battery and the quality (2)

Comment: @Jean-XavierRaynaud, I understand the autorelation, but I don't understand where 'Quantity' would be, since it is an attribute of the relation, not of the 'Product'.

Comment: @Jean-XavierRaynaud, What model could contain that information, could you explain it in an answer?

Comment: By the way to solve your error simply add a related_name to one of the two fields Product or PrductRequired because both are linked to product and that generate a conflict for queryset relation, ie the orm won't be able to solve Product.objects.filter(requirement__product_id=123) because it can be either the field product or productRequired

Comment: here is the doc for understanding related name : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ricardo Galain- I think what you need to rename is product relying on materials for production. E.g From what I understand from a typical supply-chain manufacturing is that a product depends on 1 or many materials/items for production.
e.g

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
  
class Material(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey( Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False,blank=False)
    quantity = models.DecimalField()
```

---

This is a mapping of 1 product relying on 1 or many materials/items for its production.

If you want to make the code you posted work, try this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    
class Requirement(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        related_name='requirement'
    )
    productRequired = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

Comment: Yes, that is a part, I have oversimplified the example and omitted the "raw material", your solution would be insufficient under this short example: I can produce 'cars',' cars' need 4 'doors', I can build' doors', the 'doors' need 2' metal sheets'. My inventory has 1 'door' and 5 'sheet metal', which structure can I calculate how many 'sheet metal' I need for a 'car'? (and how many hours of work at the 'gates') ...

Comment: That (specify the 'related_name') avoids the error, now I have to find out how and why, and know what changes in my programming. If there is no more complete answer in 2 days, I will accept yours.